# Chai POST send binary file

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I need to test a file upload, without using multi part form data.

```
it('Create node', () => {
    return chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/sensornodes')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .send(fs.readFileSync('test/manifest/sensor_nodes.json'))
        .then((res) => {
            expect(res.status).to.eql(204);
        });
});
```

This test call the below endpoint, where I'm using the body-parser to parse the request

```
public create(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log("req body", req.body)
}
```

But when I execute the test the `req.body` is a an object like this, not as I'm expecting

```
{ 
    type: 'Buffer',
    data:
       [ 123,
         10,
         32,
         32,
         32,
         ...
       ]
}
```

When I call that endpoint through Postman, everything it's ok and in the `req.body` I have the content of the .json

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the encode type

I've fixed it putting

`.send(fs.readFileSync('test/manifest/sensor_nodes.json', 'utf8'))`